# I keep running into TypeError while trying to use Threads along side Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, streamlit

According to GitHub we need to use

```
from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner import add_script_run_ctx
```

if we want to run Threads in our Streamlit web app script.
But this doesn't seem to work as i start getting an TypeError in my tornado package

```
TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated
```

Any Solutions?

Comment: Which python version are you using ? Apparently you must be in 3.10: [link](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-hello-typeerror-protocols-cannot-be-instantiated/29947/2).